# GARCH Use the Normal errors formula, build an iterative equation for predicting the variances in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, garch

My arma model had residual from which I created GARCH model in R.My question is how using Normal errors formula, build an iterative equation for predicting the variances & figure a way to obtain the last ah and the last σh from the output.

I know variance formula in GARCH  is  given by Sigma(t)=omega+alpha*e(t-1)+B*sigma(t-1)

I am confused as to how to find value for e(t-1) and sigma(t-1)

I am sharing my R code below for reference:

```r
#Generating data for 4 years
data1<-getSymbols("KO",from="2017-08-01", to="2021-08-01",auto.assign = F)
#Checking for Unit root/stationary 
adf.test(data1$KO.Adjusted)
logdata1<-na.omit(diff(log(data1$KO.Adjusted)))
#Order of my arma model is (4,1)
arma_model<-arima(logdata1,c(4,0,1))
#Checking for presence of residual 
arma_model$residuals
#Creating standard garch with arma order(4,1) and distribution as normal
x=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(4,1)),distribution.model = "norm")
```

I am confused  how to proceed forward and how to calculate variance and  last ah and the last σh.

Kindly advise how to proceed forward. Explain using R.

Comment: Use *ugarchforcast* (for one step ahead prediction) and *ugarchboot* (for $h>1$ prediction).

Comment: Also relate to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201933/using-the-normal-errors-formula-find-an-iterative-equation-that-predicts-the-va?rq=1 for some formula

Comment: @Richard Hardy I saw your old post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201933/using-the-normal-errors-formula-find-an-iterative-equation-that-predicts-the-va/202064#202064 your input will help me out.Kindly advise  how to  calculate variance and last ah and the last σh in R?My code is above

Comment: I saw your post but am busy with other stuff. Sorry.